# Url minus query string in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, url, nsstring, nsurl

What's the best way to get an url minus its query string in Objective-C? An example:

Input:

```
http://www.example.com/folder/page.htm?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

Output:

```
http://www.example.com/folder/page.htm
```

Is there a `NSURL` method to do this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There's no NSURL method I can see. You might try something like:

```
NSURL *newURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithScheme:[url scheme]
                                         host:[url host]
                                         path:[url path]];
```

Testing looks good:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool *arp = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.abc.com/foo/bar.cgi?a=1&b=2"];
    NSURL *newURL = [[[NSURL alloc] initWithScheme:[url scheme]
                                              host:[url host]
                                              path:[url path]] autorelease];
    NSLog(@"\n%@ --> %@", url, newURL);
    [arp release];
    return 0;
}
```

Running this produces:

```
$ gcc -lobjc -framework Foundation -std=c99 test.m ; ./a.out 
2010-11-25 09:20:32.189 a.out[36068:903] 
http://www.abc.com/foo/bar.cgi?a=1&b=2 --> http://www.abc.com/foo/bar.cgi
```

Comment: Nice solution, the only problem with it is that the `port` will not be carried over.

Comment: Another problem with this is that this will crash the app if the path is not present in the original `url`.

Comment: This API is actually API_DEPRECATED. People should stop using it and turn to NSURLComponents instead.

Answer (score 49):

Since iOS 8/OS X 10.9, there is an easier way to do this with NSURLComponents.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://hostname.com/path?key=value"];
NSURLComponents *urlComponents = [[NSURLComponents alloc] initWithURL:url resolvingAgainstBaseURL:NO];

urlComponents.query = nil; // Strip out query parameters.
NSLog(@"Result: %@", urlComponents.string); // Should print http://hostname.com/path
```

Comment: I have just found out that this method is not working in iOS 7. Encountered -'[__NSConcreteURLComponents string]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x167a12d0'. It's fine working on iOS 8 and iOS 9.

Answer (score 19):

Here is the Swift version of [Andree's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28125134/596360), with some extra flavour -

```
extension NSURL {

    func absoluteStringByTrimmingQuery() -> String? {
        if var urlcomponents = NSURLComponents(URL: self, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false) {
            urlcomponents.query = nil
            return urlcomponents.string
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

You can call it like -

```
let urlMinusQueryString  = url.absoluteStringByTrimmingQuery()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just made the change @bcattle

Answer (score 9):

**Swift Version**

```
extension URL {
    func absoluteStringByTrimmingQuery() -> String? {
        if var urlcomponents = URLComponents(url: self, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false) {
            urlcomponents.query = nil
            return urlcomponents.string
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

What you probably need is a combination of url's host and path components:

```
NSString *result = [[url host] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[url path]];
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try using `query` of `NSURL` to get the parameters, then strip that value using `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` of `NSString`?

```
NSURL *before = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/folder/page.htm?param1=value1&param2=value2"];
NSString *after = [before.absoluteString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:before.query withString:@""];
```

Note, the final URL will still end with ?, but you could easily strip that as well if needed.

Answer (score 2):

I think `-baseURL` might do what you want.

If not, you can can do a round trip through `NSString` like so:

```
NSString *string = [myURL absoluteString];
NSString base = [[string componentsSeparatedByString:@"?"] objectAtIndex:0];
NSURL *trimmed = [NSURL URLWithString:base];
```

Comment: No `-baseURL` will not do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

`NSURL` has a `query` property which contains everything after the `?` in a GET url. So simply subtract that from the end of the absoluteString, and you've got the url without the query.

```
NSURL *originalURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://winker@127.0.0.1:1000/file/path/?q=dogfood"];
NSString *strippedString = [originalURL absoluteString];
NSUInteger queryLength = [[originalURL query] length];
strippedString = (queryLength ? [strippedString substringToIndex:[strippedString length] - (queryLength + 1)] : strippedString);
NSLog(@"Output: %@", strippedString);
```

Logs:

```
Output: https://winker@127.0.0.1:1000/file/path/
```

The `+1` is for the `?` which is not part of `query`.

Answer (score 0):

You might fancy the method `replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:` of the `NSMutableString` class. I solved this by writing a [category](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Category.html) for `NSURL`:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSURL (StripQuery)
// Returns a new URL with the query stripped out.
// Note: If there is no query, returns a copy of this URL.
- (NSURL *)URLByStrippingQuery;
@end

@implementation NSURL (StripQuery)
- (NSURL *)URLByStrippingQuery
{
    NSString *query = [self query];
    // Simply copy if there was no query. (query is nil if URL has no '?',
    // and equal to @"" if it has a '?' but no query after.)
    if (!query || ![query length]) {
        return [self copy];
    }
    NSMutableString *urlString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[self absoluteString]];
    [urlString replaceOccurrencesOfString:query
                               withString:@""
                                  options:NSBackwardsSearch
                                    range:NSMakeRange(0, [urlString length])];
    return [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
}
@end
```

This way, I can send this message to existing `NSURL` objects and have a new `NSURL` object be returned to me.

I tested it using this code:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/script.php?key1=val1&key2=val2"];
//      NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/script.php?"];
//      NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/script.php"];
        NSURL *newURL = [url URLByStrippingQuery];
        NSLog(@"Original URL: \"%@\"\n", [url absoluteString]);
        NSLog(@"Stripped URL: \"%@\"\n", [newURL absoluteString]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and I got the following output (minus the time stamps):

```
Original URL: "http://www.example.com/script.php?key1=val1&key2=val2"
Stripped URL: "http://www.example.com/script.php?"
```

Note that the question mark ('?') still remains. I will leave it up to the reader to remove it in a secure way.

Answer (score 0):

We should try to use NSURLComponents

```
  NSURL *url = @"http://example.com/test";
  NSURLComponents *comps = [[NSURLComponents alloc] initWithURL:url resolvingAgainstBaseURL:YES];
  NSString *cleanUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@://%@",comps.scheme,comps.host];
  if(comps.path.length > 0){
     cleanUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",cleanUrl,comps.path];
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think what you're looking for is [`baseUrl`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/baseURL).

Comment: baseURL documentation has this scary clarification: "If the receiver is an absolute URL, returns nil." Not sure what an "absolute" url is, though.